# DML Statement in ‘after trigger’ and not in ‘before trigger’?

Tags: trigger, dml

Why we need to use DML Statement in ‘after trigger’ and not in ‘before trigger’?

Thanks 
KS Kumar

Comment: It's not needed it depends on the requirement;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you looked in [**Triggers and Order of Execution**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

first Before trigger fire and then after trigger fire

in between of these events. All the data committed to database

1. Before insert event
2. Data committed to database
3. After insert event

Means when you use before insert operation records are not committed to database so If we change the trigger context record's value then we don't need perform DML (This is Id is not generated because it is not committed to database)

Once it is committed to database means the record Id is generated and your trigger records in read only mode you can't update the values now(because it is committed to database)

That's why we need to perform extra DML for updating records.

**Note**: If in after event if any error occurs then complete DML operation rollback.

Best way if you want to update the same record in trigger then always go with before event. This way you can skip the extra DML.

Answer (score 1):

In Before Triggers, actions are being performed before you commit the record to the database. This is where you usually do validations or updates to the same object. You can skip the DML operations here as whatever values you give in your code is automatically assigned to that record.

In After Triggers, the record is already committed to the database hence you need an extra DML operation to reflect any changes. After Triggers are usually used to send Emails or update records of a different object based on the value of the record of the object on which the trigger is written