# Why trigger.old cannot be operated on DML statements?

Tags: apex, trigger, dml

I am new to salesforce so correct me wherever I am wrong.
I believe DML statements can work on already saved records so it makes sense that trigger.new cannot be operated with DML statements but trigger.old is for already saved records(history of records) so why can't this work with DML statements?

Comment: please check this stack exchange post:https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117772/dml-statement-in-after-trigger-and-not-in-before-trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger.old represents the data as it was loaded from the database. It does not represent data that *will be* saved to the database. As such, it is immutable (cannot be modified). Trigger.new reflects what the database will look like; in a before DML event, you can modify these values to alter what will be saved to the database, but in after DML events, the data is already saved and cannot be modified further (by code, anyways, as Workflow Rules can cause a recursive update).

Within a trigger context, it is an error to attempt to perform DML on records already in that context, with the presumption that it will cause an infinite loop. Salesforce prevents doing this casually by restricting DML operations on any record in Trigger.old or Trigger.new. It's still possible to engineer a workaround, but in any event, each record may only be involved in a single insert, update, delete, and undelete context at a time; if you try to perform another DML of the same type while you're already processing that record, you'll get an immediate recursion error.