# Trigger trailhead

Tags: trigger

Hi guys

I got an issue with my trigger trailhead, I could find a lot of explanations but I want to understand why my SOQL request doesn't 'work' ;

Because I tried previously to fill a List, before looping on it, and System.debug the size of the List --> 0...

Here is my code,

Thanks by advance for your help / explanations :)

```
trigger ClosedOpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
// liste de Task ou ajouter les elements a updater / inserer
List <Task> TaskToUpdate = new List <Task>();

for (Opportunity op : [SELECT id FROM opportunity WHERE (stageName= 'Closed Won'
                                                         AND id IN :trigger.new)]) {
    // ajout d'une new task a liste de task (avec subject, et l'id de l'op)
    TaskToUpdate.add(new task(whatId=op.Id,
                              Subject='Follow Up Test Task'));    
}

// upsert if usefull
if (TaskToUpdate.size() > 0) {
    upsert TaskToUpdate;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can observe few mistake in your code, If you use "before Insert" and "before update" no need do the dml operation.

Check this Post:

[DML Statement in ‘after trigger’ and not in ‘before trigger’?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117772/dml-statement-in-after-trigger-and-not-in-before-trigger)

In your case you have to go for after Insert and after update. Change your trigger code to after Insert and after Update then debug it.

Please find below code it may help you:

```
trigger ClosedOpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert, after update)
 {
    List<Task> taskListToInsert = new List<Task>();
   for(Opportunity o: Trigger.new)
   {
      if(o.StageName=='Closed Won')
    {
        Task t= new Task();
        t.Subject='Follow up Task';
        t.WhatId=o.Id;
        taskListToInsert.add(t);
    }

}

if(taskListToInsert.size() > 0){
    insert taskListToInsert ; }}
```

**why Its after insert and after Update**: While creating task we need opportunity Id based on that Opportunityid we need to insert corresponding task for that.

Comment: Damn !!I just changed the 'before' in 'after', and got the badge !!

Thanks for your help, I wasn't working on this part, I considered it as good from the start,
I was sure my (SO)Query (L) was the matter !!

Thanks a lot ;)