# Update fields on Same record

Tags: apex, trigger

In my Code the scenario is there is a Custom objects in which two custom formula field which is dependent on other three custom fields and i have to update two other field with that formula field value. so for that i write a trigger class like this way:-

```
    public class RtrFieldsOnLegalRecord {

    public static void outstandingFieldUpdate(List<Legal__c> newLegals){

        List<String> legalAccnt=new List<String>();
        List<Legal__c> lgl = new List<Legal__c>();



        List<Legal__c> data=[Select id,Outstanding_Final_Judgment_Amount__c,Outstanding_Final_Settlement_Amount__c From Legal__c where Customer__c =: legalAccnt];
        System.debug('legal data ++=='+data);
        System.debug('trigger legal++=='+newLegals);
        for(Legal__c legal : newLegals){
            for(Legal__c leg : data){
                if(legal.Final_Judgment_Amount__c !=Null && legal.Final_Settlement_Amount__c !=Null){
                    leg.Outstanding_Final_Judgment_Amount__c = legal.Final_Judgment_Amount__c;
                    leg.Outstanding_Final_Settlement_Amount__c = legal.Final_Settlement_Amount__c;
                    System.debug('list legal++=='+lgl.size());
                    if(lgl.size()==0)
                         lgl.add(leg);
                }
            }
           update lgl;            
        }
}
```

and i called that class in before update, but by doing i am not able to update fields.

> error: Error:Apex trigger LegalTrigger caused an unexpected exception,
>   contact your administrator: LegalTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate
>   caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row
>   0 with id a1hZ0000003F3rfIAC; first error:
>   SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = a1hZ0000003F3rf) is
>   currently in trigger LegalTrigger, therefore it cannot recursively
>   update itself: []:
>   Class.RtrFieldsOnLegalRecord.outstandingFieldUpdate: line 31, column 1

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update the same record in the Before Update trigger with DML. Simply remove that `update lgl;` from your code. In the Before context records get updated without need of DML.

This is nicely explained for insert triggers in this **[post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/117778/36878)** which we can apply to update triggers as well.

First take a look at [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm), and second review this statement:

> Means when you use before <del>insert</del> update operation records are not committed
>   to database so If we change the trigger context record's value then we
>   don't need perform DML.

Comment: Try to quote the important part, in case that post is deleted at some point :)

Comment: @JavierGarcíaManzano Thanks for advice, updated my answer